# Can I play flash video file on iPad?

Tags: objective-c, flash, ipad, xcode4

I want to make simple project which play flash video file from online.
I've searched some articles and read carefully.
But I can't understand, how to play flash video files on iPad by Code.
So I need help from you.
Please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put, without being jailbroken, No you cannot.

The closest thing to being able to view flash in iOS is Frash, and I am not even sure if it is actively being developed or supported any more.

You can always check out the [open source project for **Frash**](https://github.com/comex/frash). by Comex.

Answer (score 0):

All IOS devices don´t support Flash player, but is be possible to use a Javascript or HTML5 player for  video.

Answer (score 0):

No, iWhatever's currently do not and to the best of my surfing knowledge, have no intention of supporting flash format due to some argument between apple and adobe.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, the Flash video format is a container for a movie that’s been compressed by some codec. If you can get to the source file, you know the format of the container, you know the codec that was used to encode the video, and you know how to write code to convert that into audio streams and video frames, then *yes*, you can play Flash videos on the iPad.

So, to recap:

1. Get the Flash video file.
2. Get to the encoded video data in the Flash file.
3. Decode the video and convert it, either into raw audio and video or to another format that the iPad can play.
4. Play the result of #3.

Needless to say, this is quite the endeavor. It’s better to download the movies to your desktop and convert them there before loading them into your application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!   The question is whether or not you can play the video itself not whether or not ipads support flash player.

the answer is this.. new versions of "flash video" have a f4v file extension. These videos are basically a h.264 mp4 files. You "may" be able to play it in an ipad simply by renaming it to .mp4

If that doesn't work then use a utility like Miro to convert your "flash video" to a format that your ipad will accept. http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/